# Language Choice for Windows store apps : C++ or javascript ?

Tags: javascript, visual-c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

i am planning to develop an Windows store app and wanted some suggestions on which language to choose ..

I know both C++ and javascript.
i wanted to know the following -

Does both languages has same support ? meaning, lets say i need to customize the App toolbar look and behavior or i need to have my own UI panel with some buttons in it ? do they have same support (in terms of APIs ) for both languages ?

Also, i have an existing C++ components (library package) that i need to use - 
how easy is it to communicate to this library from JS world ?

I also have functionality to talk to online services to retrieve and send data back.
i am going to show this data in grid view and interact with that grid view.

There will be a editing view where i expect UI panels with buttons in them and flyout windows with UI controls (like sliders and toggle buttons ) etc. how easy is it do it these languages ?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you use javascript it might be slower because WinRT renders it using IE.

Comment: Sure, but if you use C++ you might have hard-to-track bugs and longer build/test/deploy cycles.  :)  Nothing that the OP wrote sounded like it would be very performance-intensive.